# SQL select statement has problem with column name

Tags: sql, select

In my database, I have a table with a column `Customer Name`. When I use select statement like

```
select * 
from data 
where Customer Name = '".$uname."' 
limit 1
```

it does not work because of the SPACE between "Customer" and "Name".

But when I write

```
select * 
from data 
where CustomerName = '".$uname."' 
limit 1
```

and change column name in the database table, the problem is solved.

How can I solve this with out renaming column name in DB?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) in standard SQL you would use double quotes: `"Costumer Name"`

Comment: And you most likely also mean a **customer** - not a "costumer" ....